# What is the difference between border-radius 50% and 100%?

Tags: html, css, border

I just found that `border-radius: 50%` and `border-radius: 100%` look the same.

Does anyone have an explanation on that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You’ll notice a difference if you round each corner individually. `100%` rounds 100% of each edge, `50%` only 50% of each edge. If the corner is to be rounded by a radius that is too large for any given edge, then the effective radius will be smaller.

Consider this example:

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
code{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #eee;
}

.half{
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}
.full{
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
}
.weird{
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="half"></div><code>border-top-right-radius: 50%;</code><br/>
<div class="full"></div><code>border-top-right-radius: 100%;</code><br/>
<div class="weird"></div><code>border-top-left-radius: 50%;<br/>border-top-right-radius: 100%;</code>
```

Answer (score 7):

> Anything more than the radius defaults to the actual radius. By definition a radius is the same in all directions, defining a circle. In other words, half of the diameter. 50%.

That means that anything above the radius (a radius is half, so 50%) defaults to the radius. So the browser thinks of anything above 50% as simply 50%, and will have the same effect.

I found this [here](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/559fe347e39efe4cf40005a9).

Comment: This seems to be a direct contradiction to the accepted answer, which explains the difference and also shows how 100% can look different from 50%

Comment: @DrorBar the accepted answer refers to rounding each corner individually. My answer refers to rounding it as a whole (just using border-radius)

Answer (score -2):

The actual radius will always be used if the radius is exceeded. By definition, a radius defines a circle by being the same in all directions. Alternatively said, the diameter's half. 50%. This is recognised by the browser.

Some authors decide to write exclusively, although I'm not sure why they do it. The browser just appears to have to work harder to determine what the actual radius is (in order to prevent curves from overlapping). The browser will only calculate the circle's diameter to be half that even if we use px units. Choose 50% if that seems the most logical option for your own sanity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).